# Joins in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, daxstudio

I’m trying to perform a left join from a primary table to two other tables so that only details in the primary tables show.

The dax function I used ( NATURALOUTERLEFTJOIN) can only do two tables , I.e. left table and right table

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do two separate joins.